# Glacial, Magnetic and Mossy Lures; what Pokémon do they attract?

Tags: pokemon-go

So the new Lures modules will attract specific types of Pokémon, based on the Lure you use.

> - Glacial Lure Module - A frosty Lure Module that attracts Water and Ice Pokémon for 30 minutes.
> - Magnetic Lure Module - An electronic Lure Module that attracts Electric, Steel and Rock Pokémon for 30 minutes.
> - Mossy Lure Module - A natural Lure Module that attracts Bug, Grass and Poison Pokémon for 30 minutes.

How does this work with Pokémon that have multiple types? For example, Omanyte and Kabuto are both Rock/Water, and Aerodactyl are Rock/Flying.

So, would this work with these Pokémon? Is it reliant on a "primary/secondary type"? If I were to place down a Magnetic Lure, would I have a chance of encountering all 3, whereas if I placed down a Glacial lure, I would only have a chance of encountering the first 2? Or is there a specific list of Pokémon that these lures attract?

Comment: In addition (as I'm sure you know), the specific lures additionally allow you to evolve certain Pokemon like Nosepass and Magneton when standing near them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each typed lure module attracts a specific set of Pokemon, and also acts as a regular lure module, attracting random Pokemon that would spawn in the vicinity anyway.

Bulbapedia lists the following Pokemon attracted by each type of lure module:

- *[Magnetic Lure](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magnetic_Lure_Module):* Alolan Diglett, Alolan Geodude, Magnemite, Onix, Voltorb, Electabuzz, Mareep, Skarmory, Nosepass, Lairon, Electrike, Beldum, and Shieldon.
- *[Glacial Lure](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Glacial_Lure_Module):* Seel, Shellder, Magikarp, Sneasel, Swinub, Wailmer, Feebas, Snorunt, Spheal, Clamperl, Piplup, Finneon, and Snover.
- *[Mossy Lure](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mossy_Lure_Module):* Butterfree, Beedrill, Oddish, Bellsprout, Exeggcute, Tangela, Scyther, Yanma, Schuckle, Roselia, Gulpin, Combee, and Cherubi.

Comment: There is at least Aron missing in the Magnetic Lure list, I already encountered one.

Comment: I've edited to clarify how that works